# Load Resources ".resx" from folder in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, resources

I have a multilanguage application and customer wants to edit Resources.resx files like he wants.
I created silverlight project and add some files:

1. Resources.resx
2. Resources.en-US.resx1.
3. Resources.uk-UA.resx2.

They all have build action "Embedded Resource"

Everything is working but Those files are embeded to XAP file. And customer cannot edit them.

My resource manager i get like that:

```
   private static ResourceManager manager;
        public static ResourceManager Manager
        {
            get
            {
                if (manager == null)
                    manager =  new ResourceManager("Project.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                return manager;
            }
        }
```

How can i get this resources from some folder and not build them to .xap file ???

Comment: Perhaps, change the resource type to Resource instead of Embedded Resource?

Comment: Then i have error:                                                   Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Infopulse.MSEA.BPSurvey.TypesEditor.Resources.TypesEditorResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "TypesEditor" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed

Comment: Are these resources just for localised strings, or do they have other resource types in them as well?

Comment: Only strings! Captions, labels etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a string localisation problem only, and you just want the flexibility of selecting an entire set of localised content, there are several methods out there for binding your strings to a resource manager. **Most of them are overly complex for the desired result**:

Given the following:

- Most solutions I have seen require a binding statement about 80 character long *for every single entry*. This includes no end of clever Converter use.
- Most solutions I have seen implement every string as a notify property (this seems a massive overhead for strings that hardly ever change).
- Localisation generally does not require an instantaneous update (you can always refresh the current page).

A far simpler approach is to simply place your strings, as name value pairs, in the global App dictionary and reference them via a short/simple *StaticResource* binding e.g.

```
Text={StaticResource L_MenuHome}
```

The remaining problem is then just how to get another set of language strings into the App dictionary (which is actually quite easy):

- Put your default languages strings directly into your App.xaml (this helps in development as missing keys will result in an exception).
- Pull any newly chosen language down from your server via any convenient means (XML file, XAML file, CSV, or from a database via webservice)
- Replace the dictionary entries with the newly loaded data. The only thing you must do is make sure the key is already present, or you must add an entry instead or setting one.
- Reload the current page (take them back to the home page after a language change?)

I don't know why everyone seems to love the really complex solutions when StaticResources do the job just fine and with a lot less effort. We also tend to use a webservice to fetch a set of language strings from a database as it is generally less than 200K and databases are far more flexible for updates.

Anyway, just trying to put some commonsense back into localisation. It works for us. Feel free to use, ignore, suggest improvements etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Hi Tech: Thanks for the idea. I currently store all of our strings in a local isolated storage DB (downloaded from server). The one thing my boss wants is to make a note of all language strings that are not translated - so when I work on the UI as normal and when it makes a call to translate it if it is not found it makes a not of it that it needs localization.

I do this currently with a converter - on each string it calls a method and if it is not there it marks it. Can you think of any way of how to use a Static Resource and mark strings that have not been translated? Thanks

Comment: Actually - could you elaborate on how you load your language strings into the App.xaml? I currently use a Converter that calls a method that looks up the string in my dictionary object - the problem with this is that I can't tell if it has been convertered already.

Comment: @Rodney: We load localisation only at startup (into the global app dictionary). To prime our database we work the other way around: To determine what strings exist to be localised, we separately scan all XAML files in our project and add any missing entries to our "Dev English" language table. What we call "Dev English" is our starting point (what the coders put in the XAML). We assume real English will be translated from "Dev English" by business-folks... can't trust coders to know marketing requirements :)

Comment: Interesting - how you do the scan is the most important part then - is this automated or manual? I have yet to find a good XAML scanning tool to extract the strings (this would make my life so much easier!)

Comment: @Rodney: It is automated (scanning our 100s of XAML files manually is not a task I would relish:)). XAML is after all just XML, so we wrote an XML parser (using XmlDocument and XpathNavigators) to do a recursive scan of the doc and find all string literals.

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the appropriate file and storing it in your isolated storage and try reading it from there. you could do this on application startup

Since you only have strings in your resx i would suggest that you copy your resource items into a simple text with some predefined format and reading it from there. Let me know if you need help on any specific implementation details.